# Coalesce Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two rows in a table like below:

```
jack johnson     NULL     Male
jack johnson     27       NULL
```

and I want to be able to combine them into one row:

```
jack johnson     27       Male
```

I have tried coalescing the two columns but what I end up getting is:

```
jack johnson male
jack johnson 27
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that only one row will have a value for each column, you can take advantage of the fact that `max` (and `min`) ignore `null`s. If there's just one value in the column, `max` will just return it:

```
SELECT   firstname, lastname, MAX(age), MAX(gender)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by with max:

```
declare @tmp table ([first_name] nvarchar(50),[last_name] nvarchar(50), age int, sex   nvarchar(50))
insert into @tmp values
('jack','johnson',NULL, 'Male')
,('jack','johnson',27  , NULL)

select  first_name, last_name, max(age) as age, max (sex) as sex from @tmp
group by first_name, last_name
```

Result:

[image]